# Do i need decease my replication factor if replication > no.of nodes ( planning to decommission node)

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

Now  presently we are having a Dc with 3 nodes and with a replication of 3, i am planning to decommission a node do i need to decrease my replication to 2 or just decommissioning node will adjust the data among the two nodes with a replication of 3??

Answer (score 1):

Decommissioning a node will not cause your Cassandra cluster to break necessarily, but it will make it so that a few things will stop working.

A few things that will happen if you decommission the node but don't adjust the replication factor:

- First, nothing about your replication factor will be changed just because you decommission a node. To do otherwise would cause chaos.
- Queries (both read and write) that attempt to use `ConsistencyLevel.ALL` will fail, because they will not be able to get 3 machines to participate
- Queries with `ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM` will be less available, because BOTH remaining machines will need to respond to queries to meet quorum.

Because you have 3 machines and a RF of 3, that means that every machine has a complete copy of the data. Decommission the node, [update your replication factor](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/update_ks_rf_t.html), and then run `nodetool repair` on the remaining two nodes. After you do that, you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi @riwalk this is what confuses me if i decommission my node the data for which it is responsible, should be distributed among the rest of the 2 nodes right ?? if it is distributed among my 2 nodes then why queries will fail even at Consistency.ALL ?? if the data is not going to be distributed among the rest of the two nodes what is the reason ?? is it because rest of 2 nodes have same data ?? then decommissioning is same as stopping service on one node  right???

Comment: @user6288321, Consistency.ALL means that you need to get *all* of the replicas to respond. If you have a RF of 3, then you need 3 servers to return the result before you consider it a successful query. Sure you have the full set of data on 2 machines ... but 2 is not 3, and using "all" demands 3 responses.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: I would suggest you to first change your replication to 2, run a repair on all nodes and then issue "nodetool decommission" from the node you want to decommission. There will be data moving around, but by doing it this way nothing should stop working.